# Why aren’t airliners powered gliders?

Tags: glider

The Perlan high altitide glider project has the following stats

[image]

This suggests that a glider / high altitude airliner could be economically viable and save a lot on fuel at 60000ft.

I realize this is not a complete picture, but it seems compelling. How to fully analyze this? Please list steps.

There have been a number of military gliders that are large
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Military_glider

Comment: @ralph j. This is not homework. Is self assigned.

Comment: Because gliders are slow, and the appeal of commercial air travel is crossing the country in 4 hours.

Comment: "*crossing the country in 4 hours*". Well that's not a very difficult goal to achieve for most of the world :-) We just need to slow down a bit.

Comment: @mins: In which case you could just take a train :-)  Or a ship, if you're crossing the ocean.

Comment: @abelenky look at the graph of speed. Gliders can be fast

Comment: The graph says Vne at FL300 to FL400 is 200 to 250 kts while airlines easily do 500-600 kts.  That does not look fast to me.

Comment: They *are* powered gliders. They are just much better at the "powered" part than at the "gliding" part.

Answer (score 4):

Why aren’t airliners gliders? Because it takes lots of power to move a hundred or so people across the country and gliders are by definition unpowered.

Comment: Powered gliders exist. Also with a much longer glide distance aka lower wind resistance.

Comment: @mins airliners have a glide ratio much lower than that defined for gliders.

Comment: @JosephHobbs: Yes, as I wrote... they are optimized to lift 200 tons and fly at Mach .82. Else they are able to [glide very well](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=snVifFDoAG8).